# Should VO classes contains the domain logic?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo, dao

I have been reading this site about the DAO and VO classes to work with PHP and MVC.
http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part-ii/

And i was wondering where should it be placed the domain logic. (methods to deal only with the object data, algoritms etc.)

Should it be at the VO classes? Or i should create another package for the domain logic classes?

It is not related with the DB so i assume it won't be placed on the DAO classes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic that deals with data should go into the model, after the data has been extracted by your DAO and "processed" or "formatted" by your VO, following the pattern you reference in your question.

Here's a possible structure that could work in your scenario:

```
----- DAO -----------> VO -------> Model ----> Controller --------> View
UsersDatabase ----> UsersVO ----> User ----> UserProfile ---> UserProfilePage
```

Hopefully the class names are self-explanatory. In this example, any logic related with an user that doesn't deal with the interface would fit right into the User model.

And IMHO, but this just my opinion, unless your models are extremely large or you have a number of unrelated models that rely on the same data "processing/formatting" logic, you will want to skip the VO altogether and have the DAO communicate with your model directly.